# What is the fastest hash algorithm for only two files?

Tags: python, hash

My client is sending millions of files and my program needs to say like...

> Hey there,
>
> You've already done your job for some files and they have never been
> changed.
>
> Do not repeat the job for them but changed files

And my code blocks like below...

```
# dict has key value of a file and hash value of a file content
newList = dict(getListofFilesFromMyClient()) 
oldList = dict(getListofFilesFromHistory())

for keyValue, hashValue in newList.items() :
    if(keyValue not in oldList) 
        # if this file is the new friend, 
        # do calculate hash code of this file and record it,
        # and do heavy job.
    else if(keyValue in oldList)
        if(hashValue == oldList[keyValue])
            # if this file is an old friend and has never been changed 
            # do not repeat heavy job.
        else
            # if this file is an old friend but has ever been changed 
            # repeat heavy job and re-calculate hash value and record it.
    else
        # It's not my business!
```

An identical hash value from different files are not my concern
because hash collision probability between two files is less than 0.1%, right?

My concern is only for throughput to calculate hash value from a few mega byte file.

Which algorithm is the most suitable in this situation?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes use two hashing systems and check in pairs, then there seem to be no known collisions. sha256 + md5

Comment: If you really have that many files, you shouldn't be hashing them in python.

Comment: Thanks iqmaker, is there any faster one than sha or md5?

Comment: @SparkyPotato, python is just my familar one, java or c can be alternative. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What data do you get from the server? Can you check the file size first? Can you check the file contents? To stop after first mismatch is easier than to hash everything first.

Comment: The probability of just two hashes accidentally colliding is approximately: 1.47*10-29. SHA256: The slowest, usually 60% slower than md5, and the longest generated hash (32 bytes). The probability of just two hashes accidentally colliding is approximately: 4.3*10-60

Comment: @VPfB, I can check file size of course but I cannot sure that same file size means same file content.

Comment: Instead of hashing file contents, create hash for meta-data, such as size, date of creation, owner etc. It will be more efficient.

Comment: @KIM You don't have to calculate hash, if the size differs. Sorry, if it was not clear from my comment.

Comment: @ VPfB Files of string with '1234' and '1235' have same size, don't they?

Comment: @anurag, meta-data and date of creation can be same, and the size is not the key item to campare I think.

Comment: @KIM, a combination has to differ if file changed. If size of file did not date-time will. So what I suggested is to use a combination of the meta-data for hashing. If meta-data hash denotes file change, only then go for content hash, maybe. This will save you computation time compared to hashing all file contents.

Comment: @anurag Sorry for my unclear comment, my client only send me of first created date and modified date is not there. And again same file size does not mean same file content for example "1234" content file and "`1235" content file. Please point out if I wrong.

Comment: check out [this](https://pypi.org/project/filehash/) python package if it helps your case. If possible, compress the files first, before generating hash.

Comment: @KIM **I have never said, that same size means same contents**. I said that different size implies different contents. Please read more carefully!

Comment: @VPfB I have no intention of bothering you, It just meant that I need to check differ content with same size.